# Apply level by level function in binary tree with parameter for first element of the level

Tags: c, binary-tree, breadth-first-search

How do I call a function on every node in a binary tree when using breadth-first tree traversal? Furthermore, the function needs a parameter that tells it if the current node is the *first* node of the current level.

I've tested my code and it doesn't seem to do it right, one node out of two is considered as the first one on every level. Here is the code:

```
int btree_level_count(t_btree *root)
{
  int lvl_left;
  int lvl_right;

  if (!root)
    return (0);
  lvl_left = btree_level_count(root->left);
  lvl_right = btree_level_count(root->right);
  return (1 + lvl_left > lvl_right ? lvl_left : lvl_right);
}

void    btree_applyf(t_btree *root, int lvl[2], int f_elt, void (*applyf)(void *item, int lvl, int is_first_elem))
{
  if (!root)
    return ;
  if (lvl[0] == lvl[1])
    applyf(root->item, lvl[0], f_elt);
  else
  {
    lvl[1]++;
    btree_applyf(root->left, lvl, 1, applyf);
    btree_applyf(root->right, lvl, 0, applyf);
  }
}

void    btree_apply_by_level(t_btree *root, void (*applyf)(void *item, int current_level, int is_first_elem))
{
  int height;
  int lvl[2];

  if (!root)
    return ;
  height = btree_level_count(root);
  lvl[0] = 0;
  lvl[1] = 0;
  while (lvl[0] < height)
  {
    btree_applyf(root, lvl, 1, applyf);
    lvl[0]++;
  }
}
```

I use an arbitrary limit on the number of parameters per function hence the array to represent both the level and the current level.

Comment: I do not understand the purpose/meaning of the last sentence. Why an array and why an arbitrary limit? You simply need to do a traversal and do some additional calculations if the node if the "first" one in the level, right? Also, what does "first" mean here?

Comment: First means the one which is the most on the left. The limit is imposed by the assignement (as other limits such as 25 lines per function and 5 functions per file)